# CRON Failed Expression

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm building a Cloudwatch Trigger to trigger every HOUR between the hours of 9-17 (9am-5pm) during the working week (MON-FRI)

Terraform throws this error at me:

```
ValidationException: Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid.
```

This is my Schedule Expression: `schedule_expression = "cron(0 9-17 * * MON-FRI *)"`

Does anyone know why it is invalid?

Answer (score 5):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents-expressions.html

> One of the day-of-month or day-of-week values must be a question mark (?).

`cron(0 9-17 ? * MON-FRI *)` should work.

Comment: Perfect. Thank You!